# Template method in template class with definition outside class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to have a template class with a template method inside and also define that method outside the class. I tried looking around for an answer, but couldn't find one.

For example:

```
template<typename A> class Type {
private:
    A value;
public:
    template<typename B> A Method(B value) {
        // some code here, it's not important for the sake of this example
    }
}
```

How would I move the definition of method `Method` to be outside the class body? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

syntax would be

```
template<typename A>
template<typename B>
A Type<A>::Method(B value)
{
    // some code here, it's not important for the sake of this example
}
```